# Decode google translate API response in JAVA

Tags: java, url, google-translate, google-translation-api

I need to write a small tool in JAVA which will translate text from English to French using the Google translate API. Everything works but I have an apostrophe decoding problem.

Original text:
**Inherit Tax Rate**

Text translated with Google translate API:
**Taux d&#39; imposition hérité**

How it should be:
**Taux d'imposition hérité**

This is my translate method(sorry for the long method):

```
private String translate(String text, String from, String to) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        try {
        String encodedText = URLEncoder.encode(text, "UTF-8");
        String urlStr = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=" + sKey + "&q=" + encodedText + "&target=" + to + "&source=" + from;

        URL url = new URL(urlStr);

        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream googleStream;

        if (conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            googleStream = conn.getInputStream(); //success
        } else
            googleStream = conn.getErrorStream();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(googleStream));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }

            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            JsonElement element = parser.parse(result.toString());

            if (element.isJsonObject()) {
                JsonObject obj = element.getAsJsonObject();
                if (obj.get("error") == null) {
                    String translatedText = obj.get("data").getAsJsonObject().
                    get("translations").getAsJsonArray().
                    get(0).getAsJsonObject().
                    get("translatedText").getAsString();
                    return translatedText;
                }
            }

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                System.err.println(result);
            }

        } catch (IOException | JsonSyntaxException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I'm using an XML writer to write the text and first I though that this has a problem, but I observed that the text is returned like this in the stream so I introduced the encoding parameter when I initialise the InputStreamReader:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(googleStream, "UTF-8"));
```

But I receive the string with the same problem. Any ideas about what I can do?

Comment: Expected and actual strings seem to be the same. Are you sure you posted them correctly?

Comment: Actually the browser renders the apostrophe. I'm checking how can I escape it.

Comment: I added a temporary space between "#" and "3" until I found how I can display it properly.

Comment: do you mean `&amp;#39;`?

Comment: @SapuSeven, Yes, Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this problem is solved by using the `format` parameter ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/translate)). It defaults to `html`, but you can change it to `text` to receive unencoded data. Your request should look like this:

```
String urlStr = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=" + sKey + "&q=" + encodedText + "&target=" + to + "&source=" + from + "&format=text";
```